# why df command can return fast that with disk usage than du

Tags: linux, shell

Why df command can return the usage about each partition quickly, while du will take a longer time to compute the disk usage to return.

How does df work?

Comment: Check [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/529338/du-command-takes-way-too-long-to-run) question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`df` just tells you the total free space on a filesystem.  The filesystem can know this instantly, by simple bookkeeping.

`du` on the other hand actually traverses a directory and calculates the total size of its contents.  This is slower, but it is more powerful too: it can calculate the size of a single directory rather than the entire filesystem, for example.

Comment: So, can you give me some more info about fs bookkeeping.

Comment: Sure: when a filesystem is initially created, it is entirely empty, and it knows what its total size is.  Whenever a file is created or resized, the size of the free area shrinks, and can be stored as a single number for instant access.  Sort of like a linked list, which may store a "size" number for quick lookup without traversing the nodes.

Answer (score 7):

according to the manuals, `df - report file system disk space usage`

and, `du - estimate file space usage`

While `df` is to show the file system usage, `du` is to report the file space usage. `du` works from files while `df` works at filesystem level, reporting what the kernel says it has available. Broadly speaking by its design, `df` does not care about the files but the filesystem itself.

Working wise, `df` Looks at disk used blocks directly in filesystem metadata. Because of this it returns much faster than `du` but can only show info about the entire disk/partition. Where as, `du` walks through directory tree and counts the sum size of all files therein. It may not output exact information due to the possibility of unreadable files, hardlinks in directory tree, etc.

**EDIT**

**Since you asked this also, how `df` works**, its really interesting to say that if you use both `df` and `du` you may see that sometimes there is difference in the amount of free space available. Now you may get surprised thinking how is it possible that two similar commands (`df` and `du`) returning different free spaces for the same hard disk ???

The answer lies in the working of `df` ,
As df is related directly to the filesystem metadata, it is also connected to the **open file descriptor**. Suppose a situation happens, when a file is deleted, it may be possible that some other process is holding the file open, causing it to not be deleted; (restarting or killing that process will release the file) Also if you have created hardlinks, several filenames will point to the same data, and the data (the actual contents) will be marked as free/usable until all references to it has been removed. In this situations, `df` will consider the size of those file / data, as a result the available space will be lower.

Answer (score 4):

`df` and `du` are two different utilities. As the name suggest `du`[Man page of du](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) will estimate file usage whereas `df`[Man page of df](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df) will report disk usage.

```
df - report file system disk space usage
```

and

```
du - estimate file space usage
```

What `df` does is parse `/etc/mtab` file and using `statfs` report the disk usage. Whereas `du` will parse through all the files in the directory store size of each file and then calculate final sum which is tedious compared to what `df` does.

Since parsing files requires memory accessing which in turn hogs the CPU until operation is complete. Hence df is faster compared to du

Answer (score 3):

Because `df` can use the [statfs(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html) syscall. But `du` is recursively traversing the file hierarchy, à la [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)

In general, remember that most Linux programs and commands are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study their source code. `df` is in [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)

And you can always [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) a command to understand which syscalls it is running.